# Javascript Syntax error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript

When i use the javascript code ( http://jsfiddle.net/TRyhK/ ) :

```
var test = "@[]
@[]";
```

I reiceive a strange error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line feeds in string literals can be expressed with `\n`:

```
var test = "@[]\n@[]";
```